# How to refer to data in Spark SQL using column names?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If I have a file named `shades.txt` with the following data:

```
1 | 1 | dark red
2 | 1 | light red
3 | 2 | dark green
4 | 3 | light blue
5 | 3 | sky blue
```

I can store it in SparkSQL like below:

```
var shades_part = sc.textFile("shades.txt")
var shades_data = shades_part.map(line => line.split("\\|").map(elem => elem.trim))
shades_data.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("shades_data")
```

But when I try to run a query on it

```
sqlContext.sql("select * from shades_data A where A.shade_name = "dark green")
```

I get an error:

```
cannot resolve '`A.shade_name`' given input columns: [A.value];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use case class for your code as

```
case class Shades(id: Int, colorCode:Int, shadeColor: String)
```

Then modify your code as

```
var shades_part = sc.textFile("shades.txt")
var shades_data = shades_part.map(line => line.split("\\|")).map(elem => Shades(elem(0).trim.toInt, elem(1).trim.toInt, elem(2).trim))
val df = shades_data.toDF()
```

You should have dataframe as

```
+---+---------+----------+
|id |colorCode|shadeColor|
+---+---------+----------+
|1  |1        |dark red  |
|2  |1        |light red |
|3  |2        |dark green|
|4  |3        |light blue|
|5  |3        |sky blue  |
+---+---------+----------+
```

Now you can use use `filter` function as

```
df.filter($"shadeColor" === "dark green").show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+---------+----------+
|id |colorCode|shadeColor|
+---+---------+----------+
|3  |2        |dark green|
+---+---------+----------+
```

**Using Schema**

You can create schema as

```
val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("id", IntegerType, true), StructField("colorCode", IntegerType, true), StructField("shadeColor", StringType, true)))
```

and use the schema in sqlContext as

```
val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("delimiter", "|")
  .schema(schema)
  .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", true)
  .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", true)
  .load("shades.txt")
```

Or you can use `createDataFrame` function as

```
var shades_part = sc.textFile("shades.txt")
var shades_data = shades_part.map(line => line.split("\\|").map(_.trim)).map(elem => Row.fromSeq(Seq(elem(0).toInt, elem(1).toInt, elem(2))))
sqlContext.createDataFrame(shades_data, schema).show(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

check the schema of the dataframe, you will know the column names

```
val dataframe = shades_data.toDF()
dataframe.printSchema()
```

If there are no column names defined while creating a dataframe then by default it will use `_c0, _c1 ...` as column names.

or else you can give column names while creating dataframes like below

```
val dataframe = shades_data.toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")
dataframe.printSchema()

root
 |-- col1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- col2: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- col3: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: How can I give them actual names?

Comment: @Anthony pass the names to `toDF()` like `toDF("id", "values", "shade")` in the same sequence in which they are defined in the RDD

Comment: @Anthony you can give column names while creating dataframe using `shades_data.toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")`

Comment: @Anthony case class uses scala Tuples which are limited to 22 parameters. Alternatively, you can also try creating a sequence of `StructField` and then generating a `StructType` schema.

Comment: @philantrovert, new versions of spark has eliminated the limit of 22 elements in case class. :)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I think you mean Scala. I just read that the issue was closed in 2014 :D I'm still using 2.10 with Spark 1.6 sadly.

Comment: You need to upgrade :)